# Overflow image outside container on left side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bear with me here, this is kind of hard to explain properly...

[image]

THIS FIRST PART AS DESCRIBED BELOW IS WORKING FINE.
On this first image you see a browser screen that is wider than my (bootstrap) container. The blue is the whole screen window, the white is the container (with a `max-width`) with the basic 12 columns from bootstrap.
I want the laptop on the right to be wider then the x-number of columns it has on its bootstrap grid. When the (for example) 7 colums have a width of (for example) 500px and the image is 800px wide, it will naturally overflow the container (if the image is not given a width, ofcourse). So when you make your window smaller (see second image) you just cut of the image a little.

[image]

THIS SECOND PART AS DESCRIBED BELOW IS THE PROBLEM...
Now I want to have the same thing on the left side... But When I have 7 colums in my bootstrap, that are (for example) 500px wide, and I have an image inside that, with a width of 800px the overflow happens naturally on the right side again. I would like this to be on the left side!! So something like having a div with an image inside the is aligned to the right, but the overflow is on the left.

THIS IS WHAT IS HAPPENING RIGHT NOW: where the overflow is on the right (when it should be on the left).

[image]

- I do NOT want to strech this image longer than the natural width of the image
- I PREFER it being `<img>`-tags in stead of `background-image`, but if this is not possible I can accept that.

Some Code is provided in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL2q2cb1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
.imgLeft{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

**OR**

```
.imgLeft{
    position: relative;
}

.imgLeft > img{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving max-width to image will works

```
  .imgRight, .imgLeft img{
   max-width:100%;
  }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, solution is marked as answer fyi